# What will happen when the socket is closing during a data package from another side on the way？

Tags: sockets, tcp

[image]

When the client active close this connection, and the close function return  immediately without setting SO_LINGER option in the socket. And the FIN package on the way, a data package from server is faster than the FIN. The last data from server arrived to the client earlier, exactly the close function return. And what will happen at the client side? The socket had closed, we can`t read it. Will the data be put into kernel buffer? Or client will send RST to server?

Answer (score 0):

The client will send RST to the server.